# selenide code for how to fetch dropdown list value?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenide

i am trying to fetch all values from dropdown list using selenide .
using `selectOptionByValue("0")` i can fetch one value.
But i need all values inside dropdown list.
Let me know how to do this using selenide  code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you could try to use something like this:

```
$$(By.xpath("//path/to/element")).iterator().forEachRemaining(element -> {
    /**
    * your code here, describe here what to do with each element found by the xpath 
    * e.x. 
    * element.click();
    */
});
```

I used it to click through all links on the page with specific `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Select select = new Select($(By.id("<SELECT_ID>")));
List<WebElement> elements = select.getOptions();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ElementsCollection:

```
ElementsCollection listOfElements = $$(By.cssSelector(".its_a_spicy_meatball"));
```

Note the two `$` symbols - this denotes an the object as an ElementCollection

Example:

```
for(SelenideElement element : listOfElements){
    element.click();
}
```